# LARAVEL Redirect user to same page they are viewing when language change link is clicked in the web page

Tags: php, laravel, multilingual

I am new to Laravel and the scenario is like this: I have a bilingual site built using laravel and my problem lies in let's say, for example, the user is viewing about us page and he chose to change language of the about us page to french. Now what i want to do is  redirect the user to the same page url (about us) page even after language change link is clicked. And my language changing logic is based on setting session variable i.e. if sesssion[$lang]= 1 fetch english content and if 2 fetch french content. My daunting problem lies in capturing the currently active page URL and redirect the user to the same URL after changing the language to french !!!!! And i don't even know is my change language logic standard one or not

Comment: Laravel has localization features built-in. For examples of how to do it, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to use the redirect()->back() method to go back where you were , but i believe a better practice is to define language also through routes example

```
Route::get('about_us/{lang}','YourController@method_name');
```

and grouping them by middleware to switch between languages and redirecting to about_us/ar , about_us/en or whatever but you have mentioned that you are using sessions so just

> redirect()->back()

after changing language .

Comment: Thanks for your response, but by doing so doesn't that mean that i have to create  same view twice ? And if it is right then it won't be feasible. To illustrate lets say  if i have 50 pages then for each language i have to create same number of pages isn't it???

Comment: Nope that's not right the text in the page will be dynamically binded to the chosen language in the url , ex : let's say that you have a text tag , the entire html of the tag is loaded using a translate function example <p> {{translate('about_us'',$lang))}} </p> inside the translate function you will retrieve the 'about_us' value from '$lang' file , laravel has provided a decent way to do so have a look at laravel localization laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

Comment: Thank you i will do some research on laravel localization feature for further standardizing my work !! However my problem was solved just by doing redirect()->back() in the change language function. Thank you again for your invaluable suggestions.